# Demux from 1 camera to 3 DVR's

Tags: multiplexer, camera, video

Recently I have been experimenting on DVR devices. I have one camera however I want to demultiplex it to three 16ch DVR devices.

I have been able to create a daisy chain to connect all 16 channels of one device to the 1 camera but i noticed a loss of video quality (video gets darker) and if I daisy chain 2 of the DVR devices the camera channels are completely black.

I did power the camera and the DVR devices separately as to minimize power problems. I suspect that the video line is not getting enough current or voltage and that results in the loss of video quality.

Any pointers or recommendations will make me very happy Thanks.

---

> **Example of what I want to do.**

---

[image]

---

> **Example of daisy chain**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a "distribution amp" (or DA) which is appropriate for the type of video signal. For example, you could search for a "composite video distribution amp". Make sure you get one with enough outputs to go to all of your DVRs.

Also, check to see if you can remove the termination on your DVR inputs (for example, look for a "High-Z" switch). If so, disable termination on all be the last and daisy-chain using tee connectors.

Comment: Thanks, I see most of them have audio left and right included. Do you know of any websites where I could customize the amp? I only need video. I might end up building a circuit that'll be fun.